# Your network is not allowed to request an OAuth token for this Application yammer

Tags: c#, yammer

I have implement free version of Yammer in ASP.net C# project.
I have created two Yammer network with two account (Tishansoft and FNA).

I tried to connect tishansoft with FNA through oauth dialog window using followng URL:
https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[:client_id]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]

in this I have provided Tishansoft Client id. Then It opens Yammer login dialog with connect to Tishansoft network.
Here I have logged in using FNA credentials.it sent some authorization code to redirect URL.

Then I used following URL with received authorization code and my Tishansoft app client id and client secret key.

https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id=[:client_id]&client_secret=[:client_secret]&code=[:code]

when I access this URL, it throws error as "Your network is not allowed to request an OAuth token for this Application" in localhost.

Could you please provide a solution to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://zapier.com/help/yammer/#your-network-is-not-allowed-to-request-an-oauth-token-for-this-application states:

> This error is commonly thrown when the Yammer organization you belong
>   to has explicitly disabled support for third party integrations. You
>   should speak with your administrator on getting this enabled.

Comment: Thanks. But How we contact admin. I am using free version of Yammer.

Comment: Yes I setup Yammer. But in that there is no admin link under Gear symbol.

Comment: How we will contact Yammer. Because I am using free version, when I called them, they said this is for paid version users. do you have any link to contact Yammer support to enable my admin?